# Führe (Substantiv)

Tags: noun, colloquial

In Kontext des Alpinismus sieht »Führe« aus, als bedeute es »Route« oder »Strecke« [1,2,3]. Es heißt "route" auf Englisch und « voie » auf Französisch.

Leider kann ich es nirgendwo finden, DWDS [4] und Leo kennen es auch nicht. Ist es Jargon oder vielleicht regional? Mein Deutsch ist nun nur einfach.

[[1](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Bonatti)] Wikipedia, *Walter Bonatti*
[[2](https://books.google.fr/books?id=XzcUjCkD06IC&pg=PA88&dq=bonatti+f%C3%BChre&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit5978ssXLAhVHiRoKHXmeAYYQ6AEIIDAA#v=onepage&q=f%C3%BChre&f=false)] Peter Grupp, *Faszination Berg: die Geschichte des Alpinismus*
[[3](http://www.thamer.at/gallerie/v/Felsklettern/Tirol/westliche+Zinne/)] Thamer.at, *Cassin Führe (Nordwand)*
[[4](http://www.dwds.de/?view=1&qu=F%C3%BChre)] DWDS, *Führe*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eine [**Führe**](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Fuehre) ist nach Duden ein **Fachbegriff des Kletterns**, der bei Bergsteigern in der Bedeutung einer *[Kletter]route* oder eines *Wegs* vorkommt. Laut [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kletterroute) soll das Wort seinen Ursprung aus Österreich genommen haben.

Sicher besteht aber auch enge Verwandtschaft mit dem mittlerweile ausgestorbenen Wort [Fuhre](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GF11114#XGF11114) in der Bedeutung von *Weg, Fahrweg, Straße*. Bereits zu Zeiten der Grimms war dieses Wort aber nur noch in der *Wildfuhr(e)* bekannt.

Comment: Ich nehme auch an, dass das Wort aus dem Österreichischen kommt - Schliesslich gibt es da ja auch noch das Adjektiv *führig* (für Schnee)